# BigTable on AppEngineStandard

Tags: google-app-engine-python, bigtable

Google Bigtable Python Client Library is not compatible with App Engine's standard hosting environment.

Does anyone know if there is any way to connect to Bigtable from APP ENGINE STANDARD or should i use Flexible ?

Thanks for answering in advance.

Comment: Your best bet at getting an answer is to raise an issue on https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python

Comment: thank you @SolomonDuskis

Answer (score 1):

It is possible using the Python 3.7 runtime environment. It is not possible using Python 2.7. The following GitHub issues provide more detail:

- https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/5525
- https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/1893